# Ajax success but I can't insert data into MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

**SETUP ENVIROMENT** : 000webhost

I'm using chrome's developer tool to track my ajax request through a simple button ("Turn on") and It seems working fine from javascript side.
(My webpage currently: [here](http://estacionamiento.site88.net/))

My problem is that even though ajax make a success call to 'ajax.php', once is called It doesn't insert anything to my table 'dogcare' mysql database.
[click here to see my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/740gP.jpg)

This is index.php

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Estacionamiento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title"> Dog Care </h1>
    <script src="https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js"></script>
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="video">
       <script>
          var domain = "meet.jit.si";
          var room = "dogcare";
          var width = 700;
          var height = 700;
          var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, room, width, height);
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
      <input type = "submit" name ="on" id="on" value = "Turn On">
      <input type = "submit" name ="off" id="off" value = "Turn Off">
      </div>
    </div>

  <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("jquery is working");
              $("#on").click(function(){
                  var accion = "feed";
                  var flagtime = "no";
                  var lunchtime = "13:00";
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "ajax.php",
                      type: "POST",
                      async: false,
                      data: {
                          "done": 1,
                          "accion": accion,
                          "flagtime": flagtime,
                          "lunchtime": lunchtime
                      },
                      success: function(data){
                        alert("ajax successfull");
                      }
                  })
              })

      })


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This ajax.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['done'])) {
        $link = new mysqli("localhost", "myuser", "mypassword", "my_db");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
        }
        $accion = $_POST['accion'];
        $flagtime = $_POST['flagtime'];
        $lunchtime = $_POST['lunchtime'];

        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO 'dogcare' ('accion', 'flagtime','lunchtime') VALUES ('{$accion}', '{$flagtime}','{$lunchtime}')");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I would appreciate any help and if anyone can tell me how to check if there's a connection to my database ( I'm quite sure It is but I'd like to see "server connection: OK" or something like that ). Also I'm quite new to php language.

P.S: BTW Button turn off doesn't do anything yet.
     I let 2 alerts to see if jQuery is working and if there's an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code, don't use `'` for `column` or for `table` names, use " `` " it, like below.
P.S I don't understand why you are using `{braces}` )

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `dogcare` (`accion`, `flagtime`,`lunchtime`) VALUES ('{$accion}', '{$flagtime}','{$lunchtime}')");
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. That was the problem. Thank you !

P.S: Neither do I. I just a took an example and It was using braces. However it still works !

Comment: @JeancarloC. you 'r welcome!

Answer (score 0):

you can check for php if query actually inserted something or thrown some error:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'dogcare' ('accion', 'flagtime','lunchtime') VALUES ('{$accion}', '{$flagtime}','{$lunchtime}')";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see. I mean, where's row_data[]? where should i see if there's an error, on chrome's developer tool ? I would appreciate if you can elaborate your answer.

Comment: die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link)); is the code which will throw error. try and submit post once again & tell me what do you see as error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your problem is in your query but the problem can be because into your `php` method you can't get data from ajax post body request by using the `REQUEST` variable. It happens because ajax post data goes into payload request body. So, you can get the data by using this:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body);
```

after that, you can check your request by using:

```
if ($data->done)
```

I hope it works for you